# How to get filtered value on Primefaces lazy datatable?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, filtering, lazy-loading

I use `lazy="true"` on primefaces datatable because my data is large. But this time I didn't get the filtered list. I guess, the problem is dataTable value is `org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel` and filteredValue is `java.util.List`. So, how can I get the filteredValue on my datatable ? Any suggestion?

My datatable declaration :

```
<p:dataTable id="tblIzin" 
             var="izin" 
             value="#{izinBean.lazyModelIzin}"
             lazy="true"
             paginator="true"
             rows="10"
             paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
             scrollable="true"
             scrollWidth="79%"
             scrollHeight="37%"
             editable="true"
             editMode="cell"
             filteredValue="#{izinBean.filteredList}"
             emptyMessage="Kayıt bulunamadı." >
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need the filteredValue? If you use lazyLoading, you do the filtering in the load method and there you have the filtered list...

Comment: I'll use filteredValue to statistic/chart etc. and yes I see the load method but I didn't get the filteredValue. That's the question. How can I get it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override primefaces lazy datatable

```
public class YourDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Car> {

    @Override
    public List<Car> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters) {
         //Here you will get your filters
    }
}
```

If you are do lazy filtering, then you have to filter the values yourself according to the given filters.

So your values are stored in the **izinBean**. You can access them with your Getter method 
`izinBean.getFilteredList()`

Normally you would execute a Service-Method which filters your values in the backend according to the given filters and then return the filteredValues.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the table inside your bean, like this:

```
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot()
                .findComponent("myFormId:tblIzin");
```

then, grab the filters map

```
dataTable.getFilters(); //return a Map
```